# File upload with foreach from a generated form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, file, foreach

html side

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="site_header_picture" name="param_file[site_header_picture]" />
  <input type="file" id="site_logo" name="param_file[site_logo]" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save change" />
</form>
```

php side

```
if(!empty($_FILE)) {
   foreach($_FILE['param_file'] as $key => $value)
    {
    //do stuff

    }
}
```

It seem that the !empty return **false**, and `$_FILE['param_file']` is always empty.

The **name** is generate by a while, and in future, it may be possible there is more file input.

Anybody can help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
if(!empty($_FILE)) {
   foreach($_FILE['param_file'] as $key => $value)
    {
    //do stuff

    }
}
```

actually `$_FILE` is an array and you need to check if it is empty or not using `empty()`.

Comment: try checking for `empty($_FILE['param_file'])`

Comment: `!empty($_FILE['param_file'])` does nothing

Comment: I mean chech if `$_FILE['param_file']` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you don't understand how PHP constructs your `$_FILES` array when names with brackets are submitted. For some reason, PHP do it in unobvious way.

Use `var_dump($_FILES)`. Here is its sample output of your form posted.

```
array (size=1)
  'param_file' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => 
        array (size=2)
          'site_header_picture' => string 'tests.png' (length=9)
          'site_logo' => string 'Untitled.png' (length=12)
      'type' => 
        array (size=2)
          'site_header_picture' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
          'site_logo' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => 
        array (size=2)
          'site_header_picture' => string 'C:\Windows\Temp\php2432.tmp' (length=27)
          'site_logo' => string 'C:\Windows\Temp\php2443.tmp' (length=27)
      'error' => 
        array (size=2)
          'site_header_picture' => int 0
          'site_logo' => int 0
      'size' => 
        array (size=2)
          'site_header_picture' => int 219168
          'site_logo' => int 178288
```

Some people write helper functions to reorder `$_FILES` array. Nevertheless, you are strongly encouraged to use modern PHP frameworks, which have built-in classes and methods handling this issue.

If `$_FILES` is empty, check that files are really transmitted to server (use *Microsoft Network Monitor* or *Chrome Developer Tools*). Also, web server may ban your files; therefore, try to post tiny images first and learn how to configure file uploading on web-server.

Comment: So I may don't understand... I know how to upload files, thanks. 
But you seem to not read all my questions. All file input are generated automatically. So I don't know how many input will be, neither their name

Comment: No matter how inputs are generated. `var_dump()` always work. Share with us its sample output.

Comment: To print names of files, you have to iterate over `$_FILE['param_file']['name']`. Iterating over `$_FILE['param_file']` makes absolutely no sense.

`foreach($_FILE['param_file']['name'] as $inputName => $fileName) echo $fileName, PHP_EOL;`

Answer (score 0):

Ahah, Nobody noticed I wrote FILE instead of FILES.... damn it, I should stop to copy and past.

Thanks  to all.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['param_file'])) {

    $uploaddir = '../uploads/parameters/';
    $all_file_array = $_FILES['param_file'];

foreach($all_file_array['name'] as $key => $value)
    {
        $param_name = $key;
        $param_value =  $value;
        //do stuff

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$filename=$_FILES['param_file[site_logo]']['name'];
$filename1=$_FILES['param_file[site_header_picture]['name'];

if(empty($filename) || empty($filename1))
{
echo "Please Select Your files first";
exit();
}
else{
 foreach($_FILES['param_file']['tmp_name'] as $key =>$tmp_name)
     {

    if(!(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['param_file']['tmp_name'][$key])))
    {
      die("unable to upload file");
      exit();   
    }

           if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['param_file']['tmp_name'][$key],$path))

            {   
              //$path=path where you wanna upload your files
             //your data base query goes here..
            }

     }
```